# Can I modify a GeoTIFF in Photoshop without losing the GIS data?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

Are there any edits I can do to a GeoTIFF in Photoshop that won't affect how it works in QGIS? I know I can't change the size or resolution, but how about color changes? If I adjust the contrast in Photoshop, QGIS won't recognize it as a GeoTIFF.

Comment: No, but you could create a world file to hold the metadata

Comment: For preserving all GeoTIFF tags one can use listgeo and geotifcp but it it a bit complicated.

Comment: QGIS can adjust contrast also.

Answer (score 3):

GIMP supports GeoTIFF tags since version 2.10.24

https://www.gimp.org/news/2021/03/29/gimp-2-10-24-released/

> GeoTIFF metadata support (georeferencing information embedded within a
> TIFF file used by map makers)

Answer (score 1):

You can, I just tested and it works. Method 3 on this video, at 5:55:

https://youtu.be/W0EG_fcO2k8?t=357

Essentially, just go to Raster > Convert > Translate, add a new advanced parameter with name "tfw" and value "yes", then run.

Edit the TIFF in Photoshop, then save the file - don't change file format to PSD or something else, it must remain a TIFF - just "Save" (Ctrl + S), not "Save As..." or "Export".

Comment: This loses the CRS information though and potentially other tags. A Worldfile only holds limited information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file